# Select JSON objects in MySQL by key

Tags: mysql, json

I have JSON stored in MySQL, which has multiple objects with no key. An example:

```
[
{
    "glosses": [
        "cascade, rapids, cataract"
    ],
    "raw_glosses": [
        "cascade, rapids, cataract"
    ]
},
{
    "glosses": [
        "waterfall"
    ],
    "raw_glosses": [
        "waterfall"
    ]
},
{
    "glosses": [
        "the sound of a strong water stream"
    ],
    "raw_glosses": [
        "the sound of a strong water stream"
    ]
}
]
```

How is it possible to select each object by numeric key? For example:

```
SELECT senses[0], senses[2] FROM table WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: If you're going to store data in JSON columns in MySQL, you should read the documentation on the builtin JSON functions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html and also do some practice. Try them out on some test data, and make sure you know how to use each one.

Answer (score 2):

Using `JSON_EXTRACT`, you can select objects by key ($[0]).

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT( senses, '$[0]'), JSON_EXTRACT( senses, '$[1]'), JSON_EXTRACT( senses, '$[2]'), senses FROM table WHERE id = 1;
```

Result:

```
{"glosses": ["cascade, rapids, cataract"], "raw_glosses": ["cascade, rapids, cataract"]}

{"glosses": ["waterfall"], "raw_glosses": ["waterfall"]}

{"glosses": ["the sound of a strong water stream"], "raw_glosses": ["the sound of a strong water stream"]}
```

Comment: `senses->'$[0]'` is... at least it is in short JSON_EXTRACT.